# Outlook web addin won't load due to localhost issues

Tags: outlook, visual-studio-2017, outlook-addin

I tried to build and run the sample outlook plugin provided with Visual Studio but it's not loading at all. I tried inspect element to load the frame separately but when I try I get a "Site can't be reached. Connection Reset" or "This site can't provide a secure connection". I haven't touched the code at all; only trying to run it.

Comment: Check output window for verbose messages and add in your comment.

Comment: @NilayVishwakarma there is nothing in the output window even when I am running this in debug mode.

Comment: Can you build your project?